# How can I execute (run) a JS function?

Tags: javascript

I did

```
var x = function (axis) {
    return 5;
};

alert(x);
```

and for output I got not 5, but

```
function (axis) {
    return 5;
};
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

If you use `x` as parameter you're not executing the function and passing the result but passing the function itself.

To execute a function you need to add `()` at the end. So your first example should be

```
alert(x());
```

Answer (score 4):

Try calling syntax:

`<function_name>(<arguments>)`, so in your case:

```
x()
```

or:

```
alert(x())
```

to display the output.